# Pure functional Random number generator - State monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

The book '***Functional Programming in Scala***' demonstrates an example of pure functional random number generator as below

```
trait RNG {
    def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
}

object RNG {
    def simple(seed: Long): RNG = new RNG {
        def nextInt = {
            val seed2 = (seed*0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) &
                        ((1L << 48) - 1)
            ((seed2 >>> 16).asInstanceOf[Int],
             simple(seed2))
        }
    }
}
```

The usage will look like

```
val (randomNumber,nextState) = rng.nextInt
```

I do get the part that it's a pure function as it returns the *next state* and leaves it on the API client to use it to call `nextInt` the next time it would need a random number but what I did not understand is '*how will the first random number be generated* as we must provide `seed` at least once.

Should there be another function to lift `seed` to get a `RNG`? And if so then how do we expect the client of this API to know about it (because in the non-functional implementation user just calls `nextInt` and the state is maintained by API)

Can someone give a full example of pure functional random number generator in Scala and perhaps relate it to state Monad in general.

Comment: BTW, if you really want learn about pure functional programming, you should give a try on Haskell. Because in Haskell, you are not able to introduce side effects without "stamping" your function with a `IO` monad, or if you are changing the state, with a `State` monad. Even if you don't use it in a daily basis, for me it's the best language to learn functional programming. Contrariwise, Scala is too permissive, which may be nice to use in real projects, but it's hard to see the border between the functional and imperative worlds.

Comment: About not having side effects at all, Simon Peyton Jones, one of the great minds behind the Haskell, put it nicely here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSmkqocn0oQ#t=3m17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That random generator `RNG` is pure functional, for the same inputs you get always the same outputs. The non-pure-functional part is left for the user of that API (you).

To use the `RNG` in a pure-functional way you have to initialize it always with the same initial value, but then you will always get the same sequence of numbers, which is not so useful.

Otherwise, you will have to rely the initialization of `RNG` to an external system (usually the wall-clock time) and so introducing side effects (bye pure functional).

```
val state0 = RNG.simple(System.currentTimeMillis)

val (rnd1, state1) = state0.nextInt
val (rnd2, state2) = state1.nextInt
val (rnd3, state3) = state2.nextInt

println(rnd1, rnd2, rnd3)
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Inspired by the answer of @Aivean, I created my version of randoms `Stream`:

```
def randoms: Stream[Int] = Stream.from(0)
  .scanLeft((0, RNG.simple(System.currentTimeMillis)))((st, _) => st._2.nextInt)
  .tail
  .map(_._1)

println(randoms.take(5).toList)
println(randoms.filter(_ > 0).take(3).toList)
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition, your example nicely combines with Scala streams:

```
  def randStream(r: RNG): Stream[Int] = r.nextInt match {
    case (value, next) => value #:: randStream(next)
  }

  val rng = randStream(RNG.simple(123))
  println(rng.take(10).toList)
  println(rng.take(5).toList)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone give a full example of pure functional random number generator in Scala and perhaps relate it to state Monad in general.

This *is* a purely functional RNG.

```
val state0 = RNG.simple(1234)
val (r1, state1) = state0.nextInt
val (r2, state2) = state1.nextInt
// etc.
val (x, _) = state1.nextInt
assert (x == r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function, derived from @Aivean `Stream` based function,

```
def rand(n: Int, r: RNG): List[Int] = { 
  if (n < 0) List() 
  else {
    val (value, next) = r.nextInt
    value :: rand(n-1, next) 
  }
}
```

To get `5` random values,

```
rand(5, RNG.simple(System.currentTimeMillis) )
```